# Azure functions: A way to trigger other Azurefunction in a http-trigger azure function?

Tags: azure, asynchronous, azure-functions

I need a reliable way after getting a short notification in AzureFunction1 save it fast and then trigger another Azurefunction for analysing the data and doing other stuff dependig on the anysis.

[image: short Overview of desired programm sequence]

I search for  a way sending an request to azure function 2 let Azure function 2 start  but will not block ending AzureFunction1. I though a PATCH HTTP-request should be used for something.

```
        [FunctionName("HttpTriger1")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post",Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
        ExecutionContext context,
        ILogger log)
```

I extended the request from get, post to get, post, patch, but i don't know how I can anwser the request with 204 as Update Request for Graph APi do it.

I don't know if the is a good way, but time trigger are 2 complex and very difficult to handle reliable - i tried it.

So if there is another way for my problem, please make other proposals.

My requirements are:

- azFunc2 should started shortly after AzFunc1
- azFunc2 could runner seconds  or more and in very rare worst-case more than 1 hour (worst case could be determined and exited  an moving to midnight run or something )
  so normal execution time will second till a minute
- azurefunction1 will be called near 2000 times / day

I hope someone can help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I search for a way sending an request to azure function 2 let Azure function 2 start but will not block ending AzureFunction1.

I would have F1 [put a message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue-output?tabs=csharp) on an [Azure Storage Queue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/queues/storage-queues-introduction) and have [a queue triggered Azure Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue-trigger?tabs=csharp) F2 process those messages independently from F1.

Other reliable options could be using an Azure Service Bus or Azure Event Grid triggered F2.

> azFunc2 could runner seconds or more and in very rare worst-case more than 1 hour (worst case could be determined and exited an moving to midnight run or something ) so normal execution time will second till a minute

Do mind that the maximum runtime is 10 minutes on a consumption plan! See [these docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#timeout) for your options.

Comment: Thank for the quick answer:
my colleague  warned me using  mqueue-trigger, he say, the trigger event is not relieable - there are lost triggers, so I have not looked in this topic, but i have no experience so I cannot say s.th  to that. Can you confirm or deny that from your experience?
for service bus I found no code, example or description  how to use it in azure functions.  do you a description or similar for that.

Comment: Sorry  I looked again and there are few sample for Service bus with azure function with c#. But it seems not trivial, so for later projects it looks usefull, but i get a fast overview and 1 example  videotutorial show Service bus and event grid in 1 example.. So the normal queue  trigger seems better realizable for now. Can you say how you are experience on reliability of using queue triggers in azure function.?

Comment: @ingo_ww Whoever told you queue triggers are not reliable might not be the best person to listen to about these things, as Peter explained you can use any of the trigger functions grid, service bus, event hub, they will all work fine for your scenario

Comment: @ingo_ww *he say, the trigger event is not relieable - there are lost triggers*. Not sure what he means. The queue trigger is [based on polling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue-trigger?tabs=csharp#polling-algorithm) so as long as there are messages in the queue they are guaranteed to be process by the function.

Comment: @peter: thanks I will try it with the queue trigger in Azure functions. And i set your anser to soved status.  For lateuser i would appreciate i found more infos and how to differentiate  in which case service bus trigger are fitting and in which cases it is better to use azure event grid.

Comment: @ingo_ww there is an excellent [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/compare-messaging-services) for that. Azure storage queues isn't mentioned there but it is a lightweight alternative for Azure Service Bus Queues that fits in lots of scenarios. See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-azure-and-service-bus-queues-compared-contrasted) doc